# In C++ how do I store an SQL query and sort it?

Tags: c++, mysql, sorting, vector

I have a wine database that I am trying to retrieve data from, to store in a vector and sort for structure. I can't seem to understand how to store an sql query in c++, I have the command that selects the whole table and a while loop that processes the rows but how in the world do save the results of the query. More specifically how would I store the query in a vector to sort?

Am I overthinking this? I've been pondering and testing different
 for hours and the logic of combining the two languages is killing me.

Can I sort a whole row? In my code can I sort `row[2]`?
Can I store a whole row to a vector?

Here is my code that has a sql command to get all the wine information from a database. Then there is a while loop to display everything. How do I store everything from the `sql_cmd` in a vector?

[image: Code]

I can specify more and provide more code snippets if you need,
 let me know if I am still being general.

Comment: Can you post the code instead of just a screenshot?

Comment: Why use a `char*` and not a `const char*` to point to your _constant_ data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do

```
class Wine
{
  public:
    string name;
    string vintage;
    string price;    // Maybe you want to convert to double instead of storing a string
    // and so on
}

vector<Wine> myWines;
```

In your while loop you could add:

```
Wine tmp;
tmp.name = row[0];
tmp.vintage = row[1];
// and so on
myWines.push_back(tmp);
```

Now you can sort by name like this

```
std::sort(myWines.begin(), myWines.end(),
      [] (Wine const& a, Wine const& b) { return a.name < b.name; });
```

or by vintage like this

```
std::sort(myWines.begin(), myWines.end(),
      [] (Wine const& a, Wine const& b) { return a.vintage < b.vintage; });
```

The sorting can be demonstrated like:

```
class Wine
{
public:
    string name;
    string vintage;
    string price;    // Maybe you want to convert to double instead of storing a string
    // and so on
};

int main()
{
    vector<Wine> myWines;

    Wine tmp;
    tmp.name = "d";
    tmp.vintage = "3";
    tmp.price = "i";
    myWines.push_back(tmp);

    tmp.name = "g";
    tmp.vintage = "1";
    tmp.price = "f";
    myWines.push_back(tmp);

    tmp.name = "a";
    tmp.vintage = "2";
    tmp.price = "c";
    myWines.push_back(tmp);

    cout << "Unsorted" << endl;

    // Print the vector
    for (auto& v : myWines)
    {
        cout << v.name << " " << v.vintage << " " << v.price << endl;
    }

    cout << "Sort by name" << endl;
    std::sort(myWines.begin(), myWines.end(),
              [] (Wine const& a, Wine const& b) { return a.name < b.name; });

    // Print the vector
    for (auto& v : myWines)
    {
        cout << v.name << " " << v.vintage << " " << v.price << endl;
    }

    cout << "Sort by vintage" << endl;
    std::sort(myWines.begin(), myWines.end(),
          [] (Wine const& a, Wine const& b) { return a.vintage < b.vintage; });

    // Print the vector
    for (auto& v : myWines)
    {
        cout << v.name << " " << v.vintage << " " << v.price << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Unsorted
d 3 i
g 1 f
a 2 c
Sort by name
a 2 c
d 3 i
g 1 f
Sort by vintage
g 1 f
a 2 c
d 3 i
```

Comment: Ah..I didn't think of creating temp values as placeholders for the vector. Awesome, appreciate it! TY!

Comment: @BrianDelaCruz - Well, you don't really need to make the temp variable. I did so to keep it simple. If you see the answer from Paul Evans, you can see how to avoid the temp variable. With Pauls example the instances of Wine are created in the same line as they are pushed to the vector.

Answer (score 1):

You want a `struct` to store your data, something like:

```
struct Wine {
    Wine(const string& name,
         const string& vintage,
         const string& rating,
         float price,
         const string& type) : name_(name), vintage_(vintage), rating_(rating), price_(price), type_(type) {};
    string name_;
    string vintage_;
    string rating_;
    float price_;
    string type_;
}

vector<Wine> vec;
```

and then in your loop:

```
vec.push_back(Wine(row[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4]));
```

Comment: This is similar to the example provided by the professor, thanks for the insight man.